# Input numbers and extra max and min

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program in which the user enters numbers. The program, after the user insert the string 'done', print max and min:

```
numbers=[]
n=0

def maximum():
   for n in numbers:
      if n > maximum:
         maximum = n
   print("Maximum is: ", maximum)

def minimum():
    for n in numbers:
        if n <minimum:
            minimum=n
    print("Minimum is: ", minimum)

while n != 'done':
    n = input('Enter a number: ')
    try:
        fval=float(n)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
    continue 
    numbers.append(n)
    if n == 'done':
        break
maximum()
minimum()
```

where I wrong?

Comment: you're while loop isn't in a function, probably should be

Comment: Well, for starters, you're assigning to `maximum` and `minimum`, but those are functions references, not numeric variables.  It may be that you can get away with sharing those names, but it's very confusing to ever do such a thing.  Also, you're referencing those values before you have assigned a value to them.  What behavior are you getting from this code?

Comment: are you aware of the max and min functions in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues.
You are overwriting numbers which is a package for numbers, according to PEP 3141.

You are using the functions name to store the maximum.
Some helpers are max() and min() that you can use to calculate the max/min directly.

```
numbers_list = []


def print_max(nl):
    print("Maximum is: ", max(nl))


def print_min(nl):
    print("Minimum is: ", min(nl))


while (n := input('Enter a number: ')) != 'done':
    try:
        numbers_list.append(float(n))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
    continue
print_max(numbers_list)
print_min(numbers_list)
```

If you just use those functions for printing, it would be better to use `print("Maximum is: ", max(numbers_list))` directly.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems. For starters, you cannot have a variable with the same name as the function in the same scope. In addition, you should check for "done" *before* you try to cast `n` to a float. Next, you put a `continue` in your code which causes the number to never be added. I have addressed these issues and more, please let me know if you have any questions.

```
numbers=[]
n=0

def find_maximum():
   maximum = float('-inf')
   for n in numbers:
      if n > maximum:
         maximum = n
   print("Maximum is: ", maximum)

def find_minimum():
    minimum = float('inf')
    for n in numbers:
        if n < minimum:
            minimum=n
    print("Minimum is: ", minimum)

while n != 'done':
    n = input('Enter a number: ')
    if n == 'done':
        break
    try:
        fval=float(n)
        numbers.append(fval)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")

find_maximum()
find_minimum()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
numbers=[]
n=0

def maximum(numbers):
   maximum=-1*math.inf
   for n in numbers:
      if n > maximum:
         maximum = n
   print("Maximum is: ", maximum)

def minimum(numbers):
    minimum=math.inf
    for n in numbers:
        if n <minimum:
            minimum=n
    print("Minimum is: ", minimum)

while n != 'done':
    n = input('Enter a number: ')
    try:
        fval=float(n)
        numbers.append(float(n))
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
    finally:
        if n == 'done':
           break
maximum(numbers)
minimum(numbers)
```

Fixed the mistakes in your code now it working fine.

Answer (score 1):

From all the suggestions, I've just added the following code to obtain the `max` and `min` int values:

```
print("Maximum is", round(maximum));
print("Minimum is", round(minimum));
```